# My function is not running due to VScode deprecation-warning

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, deprecation-warning

I was doing a React Project. But the Code seems to be an argument in a function. And it is showing as deprecated in VSCode.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ExpenseForm.css";

  const ExpenseForm = () => {
  const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState("");
  const [enteredAmount, setEnteredAmount] = useState("");
  const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState("");

  const titleChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const amountChangeHandler = (event) = {
    setEnteredAmount(event.target.value);
  };

  const dateChangeHandler = (event) = {
    setEnteredDate(event.target.value);
  };
```

Here is the screenshot. Please Help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `=>` (arrow) in your function syntax.

Comment: Thanks Brother. It was a very silly mistake. Hahahhaah!